# how to get facebook profile cover image url in android?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting facebook profile Image url by :

`facebookuser` is Graph user in this code

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="+ facebookuser.getId()
```

How to get the Facebook profile cover image url
,I found that

```
{
  "cover": 
  {
    "id": "1390381197912238",
    "offset_y": 100,
    "source": "cover image url"
  },
  "id": "100008211130653"
}
```

I am trying to get data in this way But it gives error

```
JSONObject jsonO = (JSONObject)  facebookuser.getProperty("cover");
System.out.println("Cover : "+jsonO.toString());
```

But I don't understand how to get url from this.

Please help.

Comment: Clarify: You don't know how to parse JSON response by Facebook Open Graph API ?

Comment: I am trying to parse it see in que.updated but it give error e.i. null value

Comment: p.s. null value is not an error.

Comment: it throw the exception and its message is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSONTokener`:

```
try {
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
    JSONObject json_cover = json.getJSONObject("cover");
    String source = (String) json_cover.get("source"); // in case you want to get inner data
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where `result` is the JSON response in String format